# PHP multidimensional array vs. flat array efficiency

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got some data in my database that is somewhat grid-like in nature.  An item is in a "row" and a "column".

I'm writing some PHP code to query the database for the data, put it into an internal array, do some processing on it, and then output an HTML table that shows it.

My question is, should the internal array be multidimensional, like this?

```
$mydata[$row][$column]
```

Or should it be flat, like this?

```
$mydata[$row . "_" . $column]
```

The code is going to potentially run frequently (it's a live refresh that multiple users might look at) so I'd like whichever is most efficient.  My gut reaction says that the flat array will be slower from the string concatenation while the multidimensional array will be slower from the nested look-up.

I have considered not storing the data temporarily and just outputting the table directly from the data itself.  Unfortunately the nature of the post-processing means that I cannot do that (certain display attributes need to change based on later rows and columns).

Comment: Why should you do a lookup after a query? I assume all your requirements are satisfied,..

Comment: You're over-analyzing your code. Any microscopic different in efficiency in one system v.s. the other is going to be vastly eclipsed by everything else going on in your script. Unless you're running a Facebook-sized operation, don't even bother doing this.

Comment: @Wrikken : There's stuff like "find the item in each row that has the highest value, and highlight it in blue unless there's already another blue highlight in the same column" that can't be easily done using simple query statements.

Comment: It can, but probably just as easy in an array. Probably, how you treat the array won't be your bottleneck, Marc B has a point.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, it doesn't matter until you prove via benchmarking that it matters, but in this case the first method is the obvious correct choice. That is how arrays are intended to be used. Array access is at its fastest with integer indices. Building conjoined string keys is a bad idea, but again, it's trivially easy to prove this to yourself with some simple benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this:

```
${"mydata" . "_" . $row . "_" . $column}
```

**I'm joking**.  That's the same reason why the multidimensional, your first example array will be better.  Your second example is just in between the two.

For searching, sorting and basically everything else, I recommend `$mydata[$row][$column]`.